# How to get the record of the last query executed from snowflake query history table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In snowflake I am trying to get the last called stored procedure with the latest timestamp
My code selects the latest stored procedure but it gets the latest timestamp of each stored procedure called
What am I doing wrong? Below is my code

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.query_history_by_session())
WHERE (end_time) IN 
    (SELECT MAX(end_time) 
    FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.query_history_by_session()) 
    WHERE UPPER(QUERY_TEXT) LIKE 'CALL%' 
    AND UPPER(QUERY_TEXT) <> 'CALL "DB"."TK".GET_EXECUTION_ATTRIBUTES();')
ORDER BY END_TIME DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

To get latest record `ORDER BY ... DESC LIMIT 1` could be used:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.query_history_by_session()) 
WHERE QUERY_TEXT ILIKE 'CALL%' 
  AND QUERY_TEXT NOT ILIKE 'CALL "DB"."TK".GET_EXECUTION_ATTRIBUTES();'
ORDER BY END_TIME DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

For case insensitive comparison `ILIKE` is recommended.

---

> but it gets the latest timestamp of **each stored procedure called**

Hypothesis: Incorrect scope was chosen(i.e., end_time IN ( ... MAX(end_time)...).

To be sure, it is advisable to use explicit aliasing for all columns:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.query_history_by_session()) AS o
WHERE (o.end_time) IN 
    (SELECT MAX(i.end_time) 
    FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.query_history_by_session()) AS i
    WHERE UPPER(i.QUERY_TEXT) LIKE 'CALL%' 
    AND UPPER(i.QUERY_TEXT) <> 'CALL "DB"."TK".GET_EXECUTION_ATTRIBUTES();')
ORDER BY o.END_TIME DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the query_history% function returns 100 queries by default, you can extend it using the attribute
RESULT_LIMIT => num
and narrow down the time interval
END_TIME_RANGE_START => constant_expr
END_TIME_RANGE_END => constant_expr

More about it: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html

If that's not enough, maybe it's worth asking account_usage.query_history view:

```
USE ROLE ACCOUNTADMIN;
SELECT *
FROM snowflake.account_usage.query_history
WHERE query_text ilike 'call%'
ORDER BY END_TIME DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

More about it: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html

But be careful, latency for the view may be up to 45 minutes.